# 2 different domains (MSM) frontend problem ONLY. We can not switch site and stay logged in

Tags: multi-site-manager, login, config

MSM site on different domains (NOT subdomains)

When logged in to CP we can switch sites.
When logged in through a frontend form we can not.

Settings for all sites: cookies cookies

Config system:

```
    $config['allow_multi_logins'] = 'y';
$config['multi_login_sites'] = "http://www.domain_1.org/|http://www.domain_2.org/";
```

settings in each sites index . php

```
    $assign_to_config['allow_multi_logins'] = 'y';
$assign_to_config['multi_login_sites'] = "http://www.domain_1.org/|http://www.domain_2.org/";
```

We do hope to get some advise here, but if this old answer is still true we must accept this situation: [Registering/Logging into multiple sites at a time with MSM](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10899/registering-logging-into-multiple-sites-at-a-time-with-msm)

Thanks a lot for answering!

Comment: Well, Site switch is only a backend functionality. It shares single domain on backend. that's why site switch with login is possible at backend because cookie and session is already saved for that site. situation in frontend is different. Frontend MSM runs on different domains.

Comment: Hi Mufi, thank you for your comment. Is there a workaround you know of?

Comment: I am afraid there is no solution for that for now